# Use Chebyshev's inequality to prove $P(X \ge 1) \to 1$

Tags: probability-theory

Given a non-negative DRV X taking values in the integers with $E(X)=np^2$ and $Var(X)=n(p^2+2p^3-3p^4)$ show, using Chebshev's inequality, that if $p=n^{-0.4}$ then $P(X \ge 1) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

I really don't know where to start, Chebyshev says $P(|X-E(X)| \ge a) \le \frac{1}{a^2}Var(X)$ which seems to be completely the wrong setup for this question, since to show a probability tends to 1 I need the probability to be on the greater than side of the inequality. Also both $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$ are diverging to infinity with $n$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint 1: $\{ X \geq 1 \}$ contains $\{ |X-E(X)|<E(X)-1 \}$. Hint 2: if you have an upper bound on $P(A)$ then you get a lower bound on $P(A^c)$. So you have a lower bound on $P( |X-E(X)|< E(X)-1)$ from Chebyshev.

Comment: @Ian Brilliant thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get the question actually answered by paraphrasing my comment, here are two hints.

1. Look at events of the form $\{ |X-E(X)| < a \}$ which are contained in $\{ X \geq 1 \}$. For $n>1$ there is a range of suitable positive $a$'s.
2. Note that $\{ |X-E(X)| < a \}=\{ |X-E(X)| \geq a \}^c$, hence $P(|X-E(X)| < a )=1-P(|X-E(X)| \geq a)$, so Chebyshev gives a lower bound for $P(|X-E(X)|<a)$.